# Sort array on nested key

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am using this function to sort an array based on object key:

```
function keysrt(arr, key, reverse) {
    var sortOrder = 1;
    if(reverse){
        sortOrder = -1;
    }
    return arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        var x = a[key],
            y = b[key];

        return sortOrder * ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
    });
}
```

It works well with this type of array, where key is on the first level:

```
var a = [ 
    { id: 0, last: 'Anne'},
    { id: 1, last: 'Odine'},
    { id: 2, last: 'Caroline'}
]

keysrt(a, 'last');
```

How can I make it work with this example, where title key is *nested*?

```
var b = [ 
    { id: 0, last: 'Anne',     data:{title: 'habc'}},
    { id: 1, last: 'Odine',    data:{title: 'asdf'}},
    { id: 2, last: 'Prentice', data:{title: 'tzuio'}}
]

keysrt(b, 'title');
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For this idea the "key" variable changes into an array of keys:  Then you specify the "path" to the nested value you want to sort on.

```
function keysrt(arr, keyArr, reverse) {
    var sortOrder = 1;
    if(reverse)sortOrder = -1;
    return arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        var x=a,y=b;
        for (var i=0; i < keyArr.length; i++) {
          x = x[keyArr[i]];
          y = y[keyArr[i]];
        }
        return sortOrder * ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
    });
} 

keysrt(b,['data','title']);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are ready to change the function signature and the function call, here is a simple solution-

```
function keysrt(arr, prop, key, reverse) {
    var sortOrder = 1;
    if(reverse)sortOrder = -1;
    return arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        var x = a[prop][key]; var y = b[prop][key];
        return sortOrder * ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
    });
}   


var b = [ 
    { id: 0, last: 'Anne',     data:{title: 'habc'}},
    { id: 1, last: 'Odine',    data:{title: 'asdf'}},
    { id: 2, last: 'Prentice', data:{title: 'tzuio'}}
]

keysrt(b,'data', 'title');
```

Here, `prop` represents the outer object, `key` would represent the nested key.

So, `var y = b[prop][key]` would basically mean you are accessing `b.data.title`

Hope it helps :) Happy coding!

Comment: It's not "prototype"; perhaps you meant "signature". How would you extend this to handle keys at any level of nesting?

Comment: Sorry, edited the answer. Yes, I meant signature. And yeah, this is for one-level. For multi-level, we can extend the "prop" to be an array. or basically "James" solution looks pretty in that case! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to make it generic, I think you can pass in a function that will retrieve the value from array item for comparison:

```
function keysrt(arr, reverse, getValueFn) {
    var sortOrder = 1;
    if(reverse)sortOrder = -1;
    return arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        var x = getValueFn(a); var y = getValueFn(b);
        return sortOrder * ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
    });
}
```

So that you can use it like:

```
keysrt(b, true, function(a){return a.data.title})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get working example with following code:

```
function keysrt(arr, key, reverse) {
    var sortOrder = reverse ? -1 : 1;

    return arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        var x,y;

        if(typeof a[key] !== "undefined") {
          x = a[key]; 
          y = b[key];
        } else {
          for(var prop in a) {
            if(a[prop][key] !== "undefined") {
              x = a[prop][key];
              y = b[prop][key];
            }
          }
        }

        return sortOrder * ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
    });
}
```

but I would propose more generic solution

```
function keysrt(arr, path, reverse) {
    var sortOrder = reverse ? -1 : 1;
    var pathSplitted = path.split(".");

    if(arr.length <= 1) {
      return arr;
    }

    return arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        var x = a;
        var y = b;

        pathSplitted.forEach(function(key) {
          x = x[key];
          y = y[key];
        });     

        return sortOrder * ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
    });
}
```

in which one can provide a path to sorting field like this

```
var sorted = keysrt(b, 'data.title');
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/cosugawoga/edit?js,console

Comment: How does one specify to sort on the `title` element of `data`?

Comment: The same way that author provided in question `keysrt(b, 'title');`.

Answer (score 1):

To find a nested property value, any number of levels down, you can use `JSON.stringify` as a way to walk the object:

```
function get_nested_value(obj, prop) {
  var result;
  JSON.stringify(obj, function(key, value) {
    if (key === prop) result = value;
  });
  return result;
}
```

Now:

```
function keysrt(arr, key, reverse) {
    var sortOrder = 1;
    if(reverse){
        sortOrder = -1;
    }
    return arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        var x = get_nested_value(a, key);
            y = get_nested_value(b, key);

        return sortOrder * ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
    });
}
```